# How to set borderColor of `UISegmentControl` in `swift`?

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

Before asking the question, I have searched stackoverflow, find a related post:

[change segmentControl border color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19041035/iphone-ios7-segmented-uisegmentedcontrol-change-only-border-color)

But we can see it is in `objective-c` language.

So how can we change the borderColor of `UISegmentControl` in `swift` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You literally just have to convert the code to swift...

```
let customSegmentedControl = UISegmentedControl.appearance()    
customSegmentedControl.setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.red], for: UIControlState.normal)
```

But I believe the code you posted changes the actual color of the letters, not the color outside. The color outside is called "tint" and it's changed like this:

```
customSegmentedControl.tintColor = UIColor.blue
```

**EDIT: For ONLY changing the border**

Since each segment in the SegmentedControl is an actual UIView you can access them directly and customize them per your needs as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34758590/change-border-color-of-uisegmentedcontrol).

Or you can set the "background image" which I believe can be set to the color you need. (Although the method above seems less complicated)

Comment: I am sorry to confuse, I just want to change the border color to gray.

Comment: border color to gray but keep the inside orange? and letters white?

Comment: right, just want to change only the border color, you know ,set tint color the border color will be set also.

Answer (score 3):

More simple approach:

```
segmentControl.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
segmentControl.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
segmentControl.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
segmentControl.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the outlet

```
@IBOutlet weak var customSegment: UISegmentedControl!
```

then in your viewDidload method

```
    customSegment.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    customSegment.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
    customSegment.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    customSegment.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We can set the background image to achieve the effect.

```
    let customSegmentedControl = UISegmentedControl.appearance()
    //customSegmentedControl.setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.red], for: UIControlState.normal)

    customSegmentedControl.setBackgroundImage(UIImage.init(named: "ni2.png"), for: .normal, barMetrics: .default)
    customSegmentedControl.setBackgroundImage(UIImage.init(named: "ni.png"), for: .selected, barMetrics: .default)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
self.segementControl.layer.borderWidth = 0.3
self.segementControl.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0
self.segementControl.layer.borderColor = UIColor.orange.cgColor
```